# Accessing varchar field containing extended ASCII characters using ADO

Tags: sql-server, ado

I'm using ADO to connect to an SQL 6.5 Server and extract data from a column storing text data (field type returns as adLongVarChar).

The column data was updated from an old legacy DOS system and contains a few extended ASCII characters like 0xFB (square-root glyph in Code Page 437).

The problem is when I read the Field's Value property the 0xFB is rendered as a "v" character (0x76) which I guess is the nearest match from a square-root glyph into standard 7-bit ASCII.

I have tried using an ADO Stream object to access the field with a charset of "x-ansi" but I'm still receiving the "v" character instead of the 0xFB character. It looks like the "v" is set in the field before I can access it.

Can anyone suggest how I might get the proper character using ADO or is there some other property I need to modify to tell the SQL/ADO connection to leave the encoding alone and stop being "helpful"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - I needed to add an "Auto Translate=0;" property to the connection string